# Putting limits on a fitting in a plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I have a graph of data, and have applied a linear fit to it, however, I am not sure why, but the fitted line is well away from the data itself. How would I go about imposing limits on this line so it just fits around my data (and preferably making the data the focus of the graph too!)

Graph output and code below:

[image: Linear Fitted Data]

```
plt.plot(np.log(ts), amps, "1", ms=5, label="Schmitt Analysis (Amplitude against Log(Time))")

##Plot Linear Fit
y1, r, *_ = np.polyfit(amps, np.log(ts), 1, full=True)
f1 = np.poly1d(y1)
plt.plot(amps, f1(amps), label=f"linear ($\chi^2$ = {r[0]:0.2f})")

plt.xlabel("Log(Time)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.title("Schmitt Analysis (Amplitude against Log(Time))")
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(-40,80)
plt.legend()

plt.savefig('A_Schmitt.jpg')
```

The actual data being used:

> log(ts) = [      -inf 2.89037176 3.58351894 3.98898405 4.49980967 4.68213123
> 4.83628191 4.9698133  5.08759634 5.19295685 5.28826703 5.37527841
> 5.45532112 5.52942909 5.59842196 5.7235851  5.78074352 5.83481074
> 5.9348942  6.02586597 6.06842559 6.10924758 6.1484683  6.22257627
> 6.25766759 6.32435896 6.38687932 6.41673228 6.44571982 6.50128967
> 6.52795792 6.5539334  6.71901315 6.78219206]

> amps = [77.78630383833547, 62.92926582239441, 63.84025706577048, 55.489066870438165, 38.60797989548756, 40.771390484048545, 14.679073842876978, 33.95959972488966, 29.41960790300141, 32.93241034391399, 30.927428194781815, 31.086396885182356, 21.52771899125612, 4.27684299160886, 6.432975528727562, 7.500376934048583, 18.730555740591637, 4.355896959987761, 11.677509915219987, 12.865482314301719, 0.6120306267606219, 12.614420497451556, 2.2025029753442404, 9.447046999592711, 4.0688197216393425, 0.546672901996845, 1.12780050608251, 2.2030852358874635, 2.202804718915858, 0.5726686031033587, 0.5465322281618783, 0.5185100682386156, 0.575055917739342, 0.5681697592593679]

Noticing I'd made an error, I managed to get the graph to update a little, but now the fitting has just failed completely.
[image: Graph 2]

I've updated the code above to the new version also.

Comment: If you could post some sample data that would be helpful.

Comment: All done. Also added update to code / graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here - a typo and the presence of `-inf`.
First the typo - you attributed `logts` and `amps` to `y` and `x`, respectively, in your fit, whereas it should be the other way round.
Second, the presence of `-inf` in your log-transformed time array is not handled well by the fit routine. We can manually exclude the first point with `logts[1:]`.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#recreating your input - seemingly log(ts) is a numpy array
logts = np.asarray([-np.inf, 2.89037176, 3.58351894, 3.98898405, 4.49980967, 4.68213123, 4.83628191, 4.9698133, 5.08759634, 5.19295685, 5.28826703, 5.37527841, 5.45532112, 5.52942909, 5.59842196, 5.7235851, 5.78074352, 5.83481074, 5.9348942, 6.02586597, 6.06842559, 6.10924758, 6.1484683, 6.22257627, 6.25766759, 6.32435896, 6.38687932, 6.41673228, 6.44571982, 6.50128967, 6.52795792, 6.5539334, 6.71901315, 6.78219206])
amps = [77.78630383833547, 62.92926582239441, 63.84025706577048, 55.489066870438165, 38.60797989548756, 40.771390484048545, 14.679073842876978, 33.95959972488966, 29.41960790300141, 32.93241034391399, 30.927428194781815, 31.086396885182356, 21.52771899125612, 4.27684299160886, 6.432975528727562, 7.500376934048583, 18.730555740591637, 4.355896959987761, 11.677509915219987, 12.865482314301719, 0.6120306267606219, 12.614420497451556, 2.2025029753442404, 9.447046999592711, 4.0688197216393425, 0.546672901996845, 1.12780050608251, 2.2030852358874635, 2.202804718915858, 0.5726686031033587, 0.5465322281618783, 0.5185100682386156, 0.575055917739342, 0.5681697592593679]

#plot raw data
plt.plot(logts, amps, "1", ms=5, label="Schmitt Analysis (Amplitude against Log(Time))")

#linear fit excluding the first point that is an outlier
y1, r, *_ = np.polyfit(logts[1:], amps[1:], 1, full=True)
f1 = np.poly1d(y1)

#get min and max of logts excluding nan and inf values
logtsmin = np.floor(np.nanmin(logts[logts != -np.inf]))
logtsmax = np.ceil(np.nanmax(logts[logts != np.inf]))
#evenly spaced x-values for the fit line plot 
xlogts = np.linspace(logtsmin, logtsmax, 1000)
plt.plot(xlogts, f1(xlogts), label=f"linear ($\chi^2$ = {r[0]:0.2f})")

plt.xlabel("Log(Time)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.title("Schmitt Analysis (Amplitude against Log(Time))")
plt.xlim(logtsmin, logtsmax)
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's it, that did the trick. Thank you!
Now onto why my data is garbage...
cheers

Comment: Out of interest, is there an easy way to remove the series from the legend, and just show the line of best fit label, i.e. 'Linear...' but not 'Schmitt...'?

Comment: The legend shows what is defined by the `label` parameters. In your case, remove the `label="Schmitt Analysis (Amplitude against Log(Time))` part.

Answer (score 2):

use `xlim` and `ylim`

```
    plt.plot(np.log(ts), amps, "1", ms=5, label="Schmitt Analysis (Log(Amplitude) 
    against Time)")
    
    
    y1, r, *_ = np.polyfit(amps, ts, 1, full=True)
    f1 = np.poly1d(y1)
    plt.plot(amps, f1(amps), label=f"linear ($\chi^2$ = {r[0]:0.2f})")
    
    plt.xlabel("Log(Time)")
    plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    plt.title("Schmitt Analysis (Amplitude against Log(Time)")
    plt.xlim(0, 10)
    plt.ylim(0, 10)
    plt.legend()
    
    plt.savefig('A_Schmitt.jpg'

)
```

Comment: Hi Kim, Thanks for the reply. 
I followed the code, but this just printed a graph who's limits were visible in that range, the line of best fit is still where it was crazily far from data, but now it is beyond the edge of the graph. Ideally what I'm looking for is a way to get that line of best fit to plot properly.

Comment: then that sounds like it is a thing with your model because line of best fit is always suppose to start at the point the data is starting and end where the data is ending, if your data points are clustered away from 0, the you can shift the xlim and ylims to start from points closer to your data other that 0 as i did

Comment: giving us the data you are using will help us know what you need, coz it is either your model is not doing what you intend to make it do or the data is clustered away from the points I gave and keep in mind that I gave `0,10` as just examples of points you can use any values you like

Comment: Updated the graph / code and added the sample data as requested. The line of best fit now returns NaN.

Comment: Could the NaN return be due to the infinity at the start of log(ts) (since the first value of ts is 0). How would I remove that point from the data set.

I'm not totally sure how to tell if log(ts) is a list, array, or ndarray if that matters?

Comment: I think the answer bellow has now done all you needed, -inf was not being recognized in python so you should use the numpy inf